# WCF service not running on development PC

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

My problem is the opposite of many problems...

We have a WCF web service which works fine on our 'live' IIS server.

When I run the code in VS (even if running as admin) on the dev machine, I get nothing in the browser, and cannot request ?wsdl which also works on the server.

The web config files on both machines are identical.

What is wrong here, please?

EDIT:
I have added a new WCF project to the solution. That one DOES show the service, present the WSDL and allow browsing of the folder contents.

I copied the web config setting:

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
```

into my existing web config, but it still won't allow directory browsing.

Comment: what is 'live' IIS server? you mean hosted? in local machine, have you set the inbound outbound rules of the service on firewall security? and also set an application pool in local IIS?

Comment: The live IIS server is a hosted, publicly view able web server. When running on my dev PC it runs under IIS express.

Comment: please answer the second question sir :)

Comment: I did answer... The live server is hosted.

Comment: no not that :) the question about "in local machine" until in local IIS.

Comment: I don't think IIS express has application pools. I've never had to set anything on my dev PC to get web services working before...